# ElasticSearch 5.4.1 Java API : Error in updateResponse.getResult() is null,

Tags: java, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch 5.4.1 Java API : Correct Update but updateResponse.getResult() is null, I inspect the object and the response is well UPDATED but getResponse() = null,

In other words result is fine but I can get access. Here is my code :

```
UpdateResponse response = esClient.prepareUpdate(INDEX, TYPE, id).setDoc(jsonPoste).get();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code where you build the UpdateRequest? Are you maybe missing a 'fetchSource' or 'fields' declaration? It makes sense to me, that an update request would not return data, which was not explicitly requested. Would be unneeded overhead to load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit older, but there's [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-java-api-update-document-getresult-is-always-null/54272) article in the ES 'forums'.

Apparently you have to specify in the request, if you want to get a result. Otherwise the updateRequest will just update and return 'UPDATED' (or other codes) as the result. On a first thought, it makes some sense, because why load unnecessary/not requested data from the harddrive.

Anyway, adding `.setFetchSource(true)` to your request should do the trick:

```
UpdateResponse response = esClient.prepareUpdate(INDEX, TYPE, id)
                          .setDoc(jsonPoste).setFetchSource(true).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to help you but I don't have much reputation, so I can't write comment...

Anyway, I found a one document and source that is related in "UpdateResponse" class file.

> - link : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/22586/files/31960a2921a514cf0443857e655d18542a638dfd#diff-ac788596bc27d4bf61332da699fb882e

[copied code from upper github]

> - UpdateResponse updateResponse = new UpdateResponse(new ReplicationResponse.ShardInfo(3, 2),
> - new ShardId("books", "books_uuid", 2), "book", "1", 7, 2, UPDATED);
> - updateResponse.setGetResult(new GetResult("books", "book", "1", 2, true, source, fields));
>     +
> - String output = Strings.toString(updateResponse);
> - assertEquals("{\"_index\":\"books\",\"_type\":\"book\",\"_id\":\"1\",\"_version\":2,\"result\":\"updated\"," +
> - "\"_shards\":{\"total\":3,\"successful\":2,\"failed\":0},\"_seq_no\":7,\"get\":{\"found\":true," +
> - "\"_source\":{\"title\":\"Book title\",\"isbn\":\"ABC-123\"},\"fields\":{\"isbn\":[\"ABC-123\"],\"title\":[\"Book " +
> - "title\"]}}}", output);

There are some code for test, so I think that you can test your code using this test code. I suggest that you use "toSting()" method before using "getResult()" method. It can be make easier to find what is wrong.

Have a good day!